# Delphi: Host Application for Command Line Application

Tags: delphi, debugging, command-line, ipc, host

I'd like to debug a command-line application which is started as an independent process by a host application. It uses standard I/O pipes for inter-process communication (IPC).

While I can specify a host application in Delphi, it doesn't seem to be used if the output is an executable itself. It works fine for DLLs, but I don't like to split my program into a DLL if it is possible to run the host application directly.

I've also tried to use the 'load process' dialog but without much success. In fact it's really just about to start a host application which then starts the executable I'm working on.

Can anyone tell me if this can work or how I can make this to work?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.  If the code to be debugged is running in its own executable process, then just debug that process directly. Either start that EXE from the debugger, or (since it interacts with its Host app via pipes) just attach the debugger to the process after it has been started. In the first case, you can instruct the debugger to pass whatever command-line parameters you want to the debugged process when starting it. You can't do that in the latter case

Comment: You are going to need to attach to the process after it has started.

Comment: The problem in my case lies in the fact that as soon as the host starts, it directly interacts with my application. This means its hard to attach my program to the process before my program get called.

Comment: I can't just start my program directly as it requires to get started from the host. Or in other words, if I start it directly I can debug it and everything seems to work fine (no need for debugging). But when it gets started by the host, this host seems to pass unexpected parameters which I'd like to observe.

Comment: I have also tried the DLL approach where I put the entire code into a DLL, which is then called by a dummy executable. Unfortunately it doesn't work either. Mainly because the host application is 64-bit (while my app is 32-bit) and the IDE does not allow me to use a 64-bit host app for a 32-bit program. If I compile my code as 64-bit, the debugger starts the host app as desired, but crashes immediately after launching my dummy app with the DLL.

Comment: I have found a 32-bit version of the host app and it's now possible to use 'Load process...' (to start the host app).
It starts the host app, which implicitly starts my executable. Unfortunately I'm still not able to debug my code as it doesn't seem to halt at any breakpoint.